# How to get data with just inserted data with Sequelize in PostgreSql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to get updated table values after I add user to my "WOD" table. For instance, I have 2 users in my WOD table and after I add third user , I want to return a response to client with I have just inserted data (third guy). But now , I can only return first 2 users because I can not take updated values. Of course I can make another query to get updated table values after I insert, but is there any better solution ? Here is my codes;

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
 try {
const { userId, wodId } = req.body;

if (!userId || !wodId) {
  res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: 'need userId and wodId' });
}

const wod = await Wod.findByPk(wodId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'Participants',
      through: { attributes: [] }
    }
  ]
});
//check capacity if full.
if (wod.Participants.length >= wod.capacity) {
  res
    .status(403)
    .send({ status: false, message: 'Capacity of this class is full!' });
}
const result = await wod.addParticipants(userId);

res.status(201).json({ status: !!result, wod });
} catch (error) {
res.status(500).send({ status: result, message: error.message });
console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a result of many-to-many association sequelize.sync will generate some [functions](https://medium.com/@julianne.marik/sequelize-associations-magic-methods-c72008db91c9) for us. You are used addParticipants function and this returns an array that added to the assocation(userwod) table.

In this array you will find some id fields(join table fields) because you just run like this `INSERT INTO 'user_wods' ('user_id''wod_id') VALUES (2,1)`. If you want to return the added user's information then you should run a `SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'id'=2`.

You must call reload function for fetch the third guy.

```
await wod.reload()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I have not known reload method. It works (update object without creating another one.)